# Does one step in Object Detection API mean processing one picture or one bounding box?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

In pipeline.config file in [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) we have parameter `NUM_STEPS`.

Does **one step** mean processing one whole picture, or one bounding box?

In the config file, we have:

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    # (...)
  }

  train_config: {
    batch_size: 1
    optimizer {
      # (...)
    }
    gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
    # (...)
    num_steps: 200000  # <-- HERE IT IS
    # (...)
  }
}
```

E.g. We've got a training TFRecord with 2 pictures, 10 bboxes each. If I have NUM_STEPS set to 10, does this mean, that I would process first 10 bboxes, or each photo 5 times?

Full config file can be found here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/32dadfc2def4f05faeedacce98e4c4099be4c433/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config#L113

Comment: where is that file exactly? I could not find it here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/tpu_exporters/testdata/ssd/ssd_pipeline.config

Comment: here is the example config: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/32dadfc2def4f05faeedacce98e4c4099be4c433/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config#L113
Maybe I should precise this in question

Comment: Yes you should include all the minimal code to understand the context of the question to the post. See [ask] and give a [mcve] please

Comment: @xiawi, ok, done. I've added info about the file to the question

Comment: I've just did it as rather expected (code included to the post). Question: do you expect to **train** with two images only ?

Comment: This is just a toy example of course. I would like to know who TF object detection API would handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One 'step' corresponds to one batch processing.

The input of faster-RCNN is a full image and your  batch size is 1, thus it means that you are using one image each time. In your case, the first step will process the five box of the first image and the second step the five of the second one.